# Air effect in scenes and dances

Tags: film-techniques, effects

I am new to filming effects. I was wondering how they create air effect, for example: many actors have their hair flying in scenes and in dances. Do they use fans in front of them or are there any other techniques?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In movies they use as simple as small air blowers to huge fans depending on the scene they are filming.

Below is a behind the scene, on making the Superman fly in air.

[image]

Comment: is that a real human guy or a prop?

Comment: @Vishwa That is a real human actor. Also note that you do not need expensive equipment to blow air. In the photo above, the man on the ladder has an air hose. But you can just wave a pillow in front of your actor. I have also used a big piece of cardboard to make an actor's hair blow: just wave it back and forth in front of them like a fan. If you are shooting indoor, you can also move a door back and forth quickly to fan air onto an actor.

Comment: @BrettFromLA That's quite a info there. thanks.. Have you worked in the industry? Where should be the placement of camera in this scene above?

Comment: @Vishwa I went to film school. I also made over 1000 YouTube videos, some of which had special effects in them. In the shot above, the camera was probably on the dolly tracks to the left, but it could be placed anywhere that it wouldn't see all the people holding the air hoses.

Comment: @BrettFromLA must be a great experience, the film school. I always wanted to be an actor anyways, but ....